# How can I iterate variable x using foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, html, foreach, netsuite

How can I iterate the value of x inside the loop? It doesn't iterate. Thanks for the help!

```
  $x = 0;
    foreach($searchResponse->searchResult->recordList as $customer => $value) {
        $custInternalId = $value[$x]->internalId;
        $request = new GetRequest();
        $request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
        $request->baseRef->internalId = $custInternalId;
        $request->baseRef->type = "customer";
        $getResponse = $service->get($request);
        $cust = $getResponse->readResponse->record;
        $x++;
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps by initialising $x ___before___ the foreach() loop, not inside it; otherwise it's unclear what you actually want to do

Comment: i've tried to initialize it before the loop but nothing happens

Comment: Can u elaborate what you mean by nothing happens?

Comment: You're not actually doing anything with $x inside your loop (besides incrementing it), so what exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: $value looks like an array of customer data right? You're looping through individual customers' data with a foreach loop... Why are you using $x???

Comment: $x = 0;
  foreach($searchResponse->searchResult->recordList as $customer => $value) {
   echo $x; //0
   $custInternalId = $value[$x]->internalId;
   $request = new GetRequest();
   $request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
   $request->baseRef->internalId = $custInternalId;
   $request->baseRef->type = "customer";
   $getResponse = $service->get($request);
   $cust = $getResponse->readResponse->record;
   echo $x; //0
   $x++;
   echo $x; //1
  }

Comment: the value of $x returns to zero.

Comment: Edit your question if you want to add details, which are needed. And IMHO, you don't need $x. See answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/23867132/1491212

Answer (score 1):

To debug this, print data :

```
foreach($searchResponse->searchResult->recordList as $customer => $value) { 
    var_dump($customer);
    var_dump($value);
    break;/*single record printing//
}
```

**POST THAT DEBUG INFO IN OUR QUESTION AFTER REMOVING SENSITIVE DATA**

This is how `for each` works in PHP [(see doc)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value) { /*statement*/ }
```

My guess is you'll see how to get the customer's id from these outputs. Post them with your question and we'll help you out.

It looks like you're using NetSuite's recordList that should be looped through to get records and records have field getter functions!

```
foreach ( $searchResponse->recordList as $record ){
  $internalId = $record->getField("internalId");
}
```

My guess is you want **something like** this according to NetSuite Doc:

```
foreach($searchResponse->searchResult->recordList as $customerKey => $customerData) {
  $custInternalId = $customerData->getField("internalId");
  $request = new GetRequest();
  $request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
  $request->baseRef->internalId = $custInternalId;
  $request->baseRef->type = "customer";
  $getResponse = $service->get($request);
  $cust = $getResponse->readResponse->record;
}
```

Comment: $custInternalId = $customerData[$index]->internalId; //i need the index here otherwise it will return an error. -> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Man, we need to see the array output. Edit you question plz

Comment: The array output is so big and long. It cannot fit here.

Comment: According to netsuite docs yous should be able to call $customerData->getField("internalId");

Answer (score 0):

Declare/initialize `$x` before, and outside, the loop:

```
  $x = 0;
  foreach($searchResponse->searchResult->recordList as $customer => $value) {
      $custInternalId = $value[$x]->internalId;
      $request = new GetRequest();
      $request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
      $request->baseRef->internalId = $custInternalId;
      $request->baseRef->type = "customer";
      $getResponse = $service->get($request);
      $cust = $getResponse->readResponse->record;
      $x++;
  }
```

Comment: i've tried that but nothing happened. thanks terry!

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happened? Can you elabourate on that?

Comment: the $x value iterates at the end of the loop, but when it starts the loop it returns zero again.

Answer (score 0):

Declare $x before the loop:

```
 $x = 0;    
 foreach($searchResponse->searchResult->recordList as $customer => $value) {

      $custInternalId = $value[$x]->internalId;
      $request = new GetRequest();
      $request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
      $request->baseRef->internalId = $custInternalId;
      $request->baseRef->type = "customer";
      $getResponse = $service->get($request);
      $cust = $getResponse->readResponse->record;

      echo $x;
      $x++;
  }
```

In the loop you can echo $x to see the value

Comment: i've tried this one but the value of $x returns to zero.

Comment: How many times runs your loop? The first time is $x zero. The second time is $x 1 ect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$customer` variable to get current index value because it's a key to your foreach loop.

Comment: the $customer variable returns a string data type "record"

Comment: you can type cast your array